# How to add date of creation of record in sqlite table in android and later display all records ordering by date?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am making an ExpenseManger app for android and I've inserted records and now I want those records to be displayed ordered by datewise. How to do that?

Here's my piece of code with database.

Please tell how to properly insert date of creation automatically in column and later use it in `select *` statement. Thanks.

```
public class Databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "items.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "items_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "TYPE";
public static final String COL_3 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "PRICE";

public Databasehelper (Context context) 
{
    super ( context , DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
 {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TYPE TEXT, NAME TEXT, PRICE INTEGER);");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String type, String name, String price) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, type);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, price);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}



public boolean updateData(String id,String type,String name,String price) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1,id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,type);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,price);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[] { id });
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData (String id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?",new String[] {id});
}
public Cursor getListContents(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific TIMESTAMP type in SQLite, so you have a choice of using, say, text and storing the date in a sortable form, such as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, or as an integer and storing a timestamp value manually. Use date/time functions to generate the values and System.currentTimeMillis to create a unix-like timestamp.

```
DateFormat sortable = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
String timestampish = sortable.format(now);

int timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis;
```

To use, add either a TEXT column or an INTEGER column to your table. See [SQLite Date/Time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) also.

```
SELECT * FROM blah ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

This will give you the most recent first, take out the DESC to get in chronological order.

Comment: Please tell me how to do. I am absolute noob to android

Comment: Added code how to make the string version and the int version.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Nick. Now I should add timestamp or timestampish to create table command? and what should I write in select * command to order by this date?

Comment: Added SELECT example. Over to you now!

Comment: Any chance of an acceptance of the answer? I know you're new to SO, but it's the way it works...

Comment: hey, sorry but it didn't work for me. Actually I want this date to be compared later on as I have to display all records which are from same date in listview. So, how do I
1) insert current date in String (probably)
2) later on check in listadapter that which records(expenses) belong to a date and then club them date wise

Comment: Sorry, not here as a personal support. My answer did exactly what your question asked for.